# Best way to set value of selection in php

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

i'm looking vor a nice way to set the value of an html dynamic with php based on data from a database. Currently it looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="displayNavigation" id="displayNavigation">
    @if(isset($site['displayNavigation']) and $site['displayNavigation'] == 1)
        <option value="1" selected>Yes</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    @elseif(isset($site['displayNavigation']) and $site['displayNavigation'] == 0)
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="0" selected>No</option>
    @else
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    @endif
</select>
```

I think that is not the right way to set the value for a select list with more then 10 options.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/set-selected-option-in-dynamically-created-drop-down-menu

Comment: That looks nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `@if` condition inside the `<option>` and set `selected` attribute

```
<select class="form-control" name="displayNavigation" id="displayNavigation">
        <option value="1" @if($site['displayNavigation'] == 1) selected @endif>Yes</option>
        <option value="0" @if($site['displayNavigation'] == 0) selected @endif>No</option>
    @endif
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give a try with below code if it helps for you

```
<select class="form-control" name="displayNavigation" id="displayNavigation">   
    <option value="1" @if(isset($site['displayNavigation']) and $site['displayNavigation'] == 1) selected @endif>Yes</option>
    <option value="0" @if(isset($site['displayNavigation']) and $site['displayNavigation'] == 0) selected @endif>No</option>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

A **PHP 7** answer using [null coalescing operator `??`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
<select class="form-control" name="displayNavigation" id="displayNavigation">
    <option value="1" <?php echo ($site['displayNavigation'] ?? 2) == 1 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="0" <?php echo ($site['displayNavigation'] ?? 2) == 0 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>No</option>
</select>
```

If you are **under PHP 7** just do the same using `isset()`:

```
<select class="form-control" name="displayNavigation" id="displayNavigation">
    <option value="1" <?php echo isset($site['displayNavigation']) && $site['displayNavigation'] == 1 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="0" <?php echo isset($site['displayNavigation']) && $site['displayNavigation'] == 0 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if-else statement needs to be modified . This code will solve your problem .

```
<select class="form-control" name="displayNavigation" id="displayNavigation">
    <option value="1" <?php if(isset($site['displayNavigation']) and $site['displayNavigation'] == 1){?>selected<?php } ?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="0" <?php if(isset($site['displayNavigation']) and $site['displayNavigation'] == 0){?>selected<?php } ?>>No</option>
</select>
```